# Cross referencing a second dataframe to find values

Tags: r, join, aggregate-functions, summarize, cross-reference

I have two dataframes in R I am working with. Many many lines of actual data.

data source, lots of lines of data with many locations that are the same but with different values in Num_Horses column: **df1**:

| Location | Code | Num_Horses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rocky Point | 112 | 65 |
| Clear Bay | 114 | 32 |
| Port Safety | 115 | 22 |
| Sandy Beach | 112 | 14 |

And

location reference guide, which is a table with all the known place names in the area, and their corresponding attributes: **refdf**:

| Location | Code | SubCode | County | District |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rocky Point | 112 | 12 | red | 5584 |
| Clear Bay | 114 | 22 | nelson | 5546 |
| Port Safety | 115 | 13 | grip | 5594 |
| Sandy Beach | 112 | 14 | red | 5523 |

I would like use df1$Location to reference refdf and add new columns (Code, Subcode, County, District) to
df1, while retaining other columns in df1. I want the end product to look something like the below:

| Location | Code | SubCode | County | District | Num_Horses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rocky Point | 112 | 12 | red | 5584 | 65 |
| Clear Bay | 114 | 22 | nelson | 5546 | 32 |
| Port Safety | 115 | 13 | grip | 5594 | 22 |
| Sandy Beach | 112 | 14 | red | 5523 | 14 |

Any recommendations on code for this code?
Thanks!

I am looking for a starting point, because I am unsure on how to write a logical statement something like:

IF df1$Location = refdf$location, THEN assign df1 row of data corresponding Code, Subcode, County, and District from refdf.